# Populate a Map based on another map and selected values

Tags: javascript

I have a `Map` like this with me.

```
k1: ["x", "y"]
k2: ["x", "z"]
k3: ["x", "y"]
k4: ["x", "z"]
k5: ["x", "z"]
k6: ["k", "a"]
k7: ["m", "b"]
```

I have a list of values with me like this

```
[["x", "y"], ["x", "z"]]
```

I also have another `Map` with me that have same keys as that of first map but different values like this

```
k1: 0
k2: 0
k3: 0
k4: 0
k5: 0
k6: 0
k7: 0
```

I want to replace the value of the keys in the Second map with `1` if the corresponding value of that particular key in the First map is present in the list given.

The expected output is like this

```
k1: 1
k2: 1
k3: 1
k4: 1
k5: 1
k6: 0
k7: 0
```

I can achieve with this multiple looping over the keys of the maps, but the maps I have are very large (1M+ entries). I want to find the most efficient method that could achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sets. Only one loop needed (apart from the implicit loop that creates `valsSet`), and lookup speed is a non-issue.

EDIT: The question was substantially changed; this answer is changed in response. The edit was necessary because, unlike strings where `"key2" == "key2"`, with arrays `["x", "y"] != ["x", "y"]`, so simple `Set` lookup (`valsLookup.has(["x", "y"])`) is not possible.

```
let a = new Map(Object.entries({
  k1: ["x", "y"], k2: ["x", "z"], k3: ["x", "y"], k4: ["x", "z"], k5: ["x", "z"], k6: ["k", "a"], k7: ["m", "b"]
}));
let b = new Map(Object.entries({
  k1: 0, k2: 0, k3: 0, k4: 0, k5: 0, k6: 0, k7: 0,
}));
let vals = [["x", "y"], ["x", "z"]];

let valsLookup = vals.reduce((m, [x, y], i) => {
  let s = m.get(x);
  if (!s) m.set(x, s = new Set());
  s.add(y);
  return m;
}, new Map());

a.forEach(([x, y], i) => {
  let vx = valsLookup.get(x);
  if (vx && vx.has(y)) b.set(i, 1);
});
console.log(b);
// => Map {
//      'k1' => 1,
//      'k2' => 1,
//      'k3' => 1,
//      'k4' => 1,
//      'k5' => 1,
//      'k6' => 0,
//      'k7' => 0 }
```

Comment: eventhough it is working for the sample map that I pasted in the question I am not able to make in work on the actual map that I am working on

Comment: I am updating the question. Please hold on

Comment: I have updated the question, actually my value of the first map is an array with 2 values in it.

Comment: That's quite different though. Is the first element always `"x"`? Do you require both elements to be equal? Is `["x", "y"]` equal to `["y", "x"]`? Are `["x", "y"]` in the first array coreferent with `["x", "y"]` in the list of values, or merely equal? Are the two elements always both strings?

Comment: both will be strings and it is order specific ie ["x", ''y"] and ["y", "x"] are different. First element can vary. I have updated to show the difference

Comment: Changed to reflect the question. The lookup set is changed to map of sets for lookup by two elements.

Comment: I works. I have another problem in which the values will be array of floats. What changes should I make for that case.?

Comment: Shouldn't be any. If they are objects, or if the number of items is not always 2, then you need code changes.

Comment: what to do if they are objects.?

Comment: Same thing I did - deconstruct them and look them up by components. Or you can use `JSON.stringify` form as a `Set` element (that would have worked also with the previous answer, since it gives you a nice string that is look-up-able); though it costs you a bit of speed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temp object to store list values as an object for O1 read.

```js
var listObj = ["val1", "val2"].reduce((acc, item)=>({...acc, [item]: true}), {})

var obj1 = {
 k1: "val1"
}

var obj2 = {k1: 0, k2: 0, k3: 0}

console.log(Object.keys(obj2).reduce((acc, key)=>({...acc, [key]: listObj[obj1[key]] ? 1 : 0}), {}))
```